Parse data from Google Directions API using GSON
My api response is this -
{
"geocoded_waypoints": [],
"routes": [
{
"bounds": {},
"copyrights": "Map data ©2024",
"legs": [
{
"distance": {
"text": "22.7 km",
"value": 22733
},
"duration": {
"text": "56 mins",
"value": 3358
},
"end_address": "B-14, opp. Defence Colony, near Lajpat Nagar Metro Station, Block A, Lajpat Nagar II, Lajpat Nagar, New Delhi, Delhi 110024, India",
"end_location": {},
"start_address": "C5M9+9XG, Southend Dr, Dera Village, Dera Mandi, New Delhi, Delhi 110074, India",
"start_location": {},
"steps": [],
"traffic_speed_entry": [],
"via_waypoint": []
}
],
"overview_polyline": {},
"summary": "SSN Marg",
"warnings": [],
"waypoint_order": []
}
],
"status": "OK"
}

The values I require are -

Under Distance - (text:22.7 km)
Under Duration - (text:56 min)
end_address.

For simplicity, I took JSONArray response from "routes".
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("routes");
                            Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<DirectionsApiResponse>>(){}.getType();
                            List<DirectionsApiResponse> directionsApiResponseList =
                                        new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray.toString(), collectionType);
                            Log.d("ABCDE", directionsApiResponseList.get(0).getLegsList().get(0).getEnd_address());
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

And this is the class DirectionsApiResponse for using GSON -
import java.util.List;
public class DirectionsApiResponse {
    private List<legs> legsList;
    public List<legs> getLegsList() {
        return legsList;
    }
    public void setLegsList(List<legs> legsList) {
        this.legsList = legsList;
    }
}
class legs {
    private distance distance;
    private duration duration;
    private String end_address;
    public distance getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }
    public void setDistance(distance distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }
    public duration getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }
    public void setDuration(duration duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }
    public String getEnd_address() {
        return end_address;
    }
    public void setEnd_address(String end_address) {
        this.end_address = end_address;
    }
}
class distance {
    private String text;
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
class duration {
    private String text;
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}

I created getter as well as setter for all just in case.
If try to get results from -

directionsApiResponse.getLegsList().toString()
directionsApiResponseList.get(0).getLegsList().get(0).getEnd_address()

It is throwing "NullPointerException". I can crearly see that "routes" is an array and it has 1 element at position 0 and "legs" also has 1 element at position 0.
Questions -

What am I doing wrong ?
And Is there any written code from Google to parse JSON response from Directions API where I can just remove the elements of GSON not required by me ?


This question is similar to: Object Serialization to JSON (using Gson). How to set field names in UpperCamelCase?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Note: It is not exactly the same as the linked question above, but the underlying issue is the same: In the JSON data the field is named legs; in your class it is named legsList. Either rename the field or use one of the solutions from the above linked question.

Renaming legsList to legs worked. Later I used Serialized to use the variable names I preferred

I do not know what library you are using but JSONArray is definetly not from GSON, also why use GSON, is https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson not good enough in your case? Also another point please rename the classes to upper case and dont use snake case for the property names unless you will do it everywhere, camel-case is more prefered.

I do not know what library you are using Seems (to me) to be explicitly stated in the question that GSON is the library being used.
